# MySQL Subquery Display in UPPERCASE

Tags: c#, mysql, uppercase

[DONE] for those who need this.. I will edit this and put the answer below..

How to make LName and FName all CAPS using subquery?
I already make all LName and FName CAPS but not in subquery using this code

```
Select UPPER(LName) AS "Lastname", UPPER(FName) AS "Firstname" FROM Trainers;
```

OUTPUT:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Lastname  | Firstname |
+-----------+-----------+
| MONTANO   | GERALD    |
| ALEJANDRO | LEONARD   |
| MONTEZ    | GARY      |
| GUILLERMO | JACKIE    |
| SANCHEZ   | VERNA     |
| GABORNI   | MICHELLE  |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Table Trainers

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------+
| TrainerNo | LName     | FName    | Rate  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------+
| 00804871  | Montano   | Gerald   | 200   |
| 00807461  | Alejandro | Leonard  | 175   |
| 00807462  | Montez    | Gary     | 150   |
| 00823253  | Guillermo | Jackie   | 200   |
| 00827320  | Sanchez   | Verna    | 125   |
| 00845907  | Gaborni   | Michelle | 150   |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

ANSWER:

```
Select UPPER(Lname) AS "Lastname", UPPER(FName) AS "Firstname" from Trainers Where Rate <= (Select Max(Rate) from Trainers);
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: how to get the ouput(at the top) using subquery

Comment: Please provide your query.

Comment: please make clear your questions mean, & provide the query in which you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to return the first name concatenated with the second name in upper case in a sub-query. Then you can do this.

```
Select * from Table Name, (Select UPPER(LName) + UPPER(FName) FROM Trainers) as Name
```